# Using GDB to inspect the Machine Stack

Tags: gdb

Is there any way to get GDB to print the last "n" values pushed on the machine's stack. For example, currently if I want to inspect the contents of the stack I do the following (assuming x86 architecture):

```
(gdb) # get last value pushed on stack
(gdb) p *(int *)($esp)
(gdb) # get 2nd to last value pushed on stack
(gdb) p *(int *)($esp + 4)
```

Is there a better way to view the machine stack? Printed nicely, maybe?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Examine 16 words on the top of stack:

```
x/16wx $esp
```

The "w" is for printing words